# Warnings while organising variables and functions in C over multiple header and source files

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

For the first time i was trying to write an actual professional C code for a simple program.

1)I made a header file name Essential_data.h and declared all my functions and global variables in that. I had declared all my variables as extern.. And all function declaration were made normally

eg:

```
void test ();
extern int x;
```

2)Then i made another header file named main_data.h and defined all my global variables there.
for eg:`int x`;

3)I then made corresponding source files containing the definition of the respective functions and included main_data.h in sourcefiles that needed that global variable.

thats all. After when i compiled the project i got many warnings for all functions as

> Implicit declaration of function test [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

so after that i did the following

1) I put an extern in front of the functions declarations in Essential_data.h.
for eg:

```
extern void test();
```

2) in the main_data.h i declared the functions normally and wrote

```
void test ();
```

both the times my Essential_data.h was in the main function only and no where else.

And then recompiled and later all the warnings disappeared.

So was that the right method or is there any other way of organising them more efficiently?

Comment: what "write method" are you referring to in the last sentence?

Comment: Right method as in i wanted to say that whatever i did was standard programming or not?? I mean is this the way profession organize their header and source files?

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

- One or more `.h` files containing extern declarations (functions and objects). These files needs to be included by the `.c` files that need those symbols. You shouldn't have multiple declarations (**each identifier should be declared exactly once**)
- One or more `.c` files in which you define the functions and objects

In your example:

```
/* essential_data.h */
void test ();
extern int x;

/* something.c */
#include "essential_data.h"

int x;
void test()
{
    /* ... */
}

/* main.c */
#include "essential_data.h"

/* ... */
```

Comment: I had exactly the same pattern except that i had included the essential_data.h only in the main file.

Comment: UPDATE: I deleted all the extern functions declaration from main_data.h and just included Essential_data.h in the source files of the functions, and the warnings are gone.. Thanks cnicutar!!